# Create REST full service using Node js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to build a node application using REST, need to read data from readymade api and store it in class for temp, and then save it to MySQL. Can anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple job.

Let's consider Typescript, but you can achieve the same result with JavaScript. I'll be using node-fetch as an example of the rest API library. Do note that the code might not be syntactically correct.

First: **Create interfaces/classes that reflect the data you will receive from the REST API**

```
interface Food {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    ...
}
```

Second: 
**Create a Repository**

Create a class Repository which you will use to communicate with the rest API

```
class Repository {
    async function getFoods(...args): List<Food> {
        let foods = await fetch({url: "url"});
        return foods;
    }

    async function addFood(food: Food): Response {
        let response = await fetch({
            url: "url-to-add-food",
            method: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(food)
        });
    }
}
```

Third: 
**Use the repository to fetch the data and use conventional methods to save it to a MySQL database**

```
let foods = await repository.getFoods();
foods.forEach(food => {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO foods SET ?', food, 
        function (err, resp) {
            if (err) throw err;
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi @Minasploit..  could you please assist me, how to call readymade API in our rest-in-point? and then how to store its response in an array and then set the values of response using setters & getters of our class? using javascript.

Comment: @ram, that feels like a full course. Check out the node-fetch module for making calls to APIs. You can Google the rest of your questions and you'll definitely find results